# Is Blender the only open source Non-destructive editor?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, render-layers, blend-modes

Blender's "Nodes" function seems to make it a non-destructive editor.

The "Mix" node enables the user to composite using "blend modes".
For me, the "Add" blend mode is the most important of these blend modes but often it the Add blend mode **is not** included in compositing tools.
This and the fact that Blender is seemingly non-destructive is the reason I'm using Blender.

I am currently using Blender as a 2D compositor only, meaning that my "RenderLayers" nodes provide Blender with an image that mocks a 2D vector (as though I were using Adobe After Effects's "Shapes" tool to composite onto image/video). I have always to ensure the camera is pointing 100% downwards i.e. in-line with the z-axis.

The problem is that Blender takes a long time to composite; The whole process seems extremely inefficient when I compare Blender with Adobe After Effects.

Please could you advise me on whether I should quit using Blender for this application?
Thank you for your time

Comment: Whether you continue to use Blender or not is entirely your choice. As for some compositors not including the "Add" blending mode, try looking for "Linear Dodge", "Linear Blend" or even "Screen", as they are very similar or the same.

Comment: It's up to you to use whatever software you think gets the job done. The compositor is indeed slow compared to other software. Read this thread: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?336647-Performance-in-the-compositor&highlight=compositor+slow. Blender is not the only node-based compositor, but is certainly the only free and open source one. Other node based compositing programs cost quite a few thousand dollars. All of them do have a bunch of transfer modes to play with. For "shapes" in blender take a look at the masking/tracking tools on the movie clip editor and the mask node.

Comment: If you are just using it for compositing existing 2D images, you might get a speed boost by using an [*image node*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Composite_Nodes/Types/Input#Image_node) to include your images.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is only performance, Blender can also leverage OpenCL running on the GPU and CPU to speed up the node compositing. From my experience, it significantly speeds up the process.

You can turn it on in the node editor panel.

[image]